# Please provide tag wikis!

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I'm always a big fan of tag wikis, but I think they're even more useful for native speakers of English when the tag names are French.

At the very least, I think [débutant](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d%c3%a9butant) and [études](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tudes) should have tag wikis, as people asking those questions are most likely to need a tag wiki indicating what it means in English.

Comment: I've added a synonym [tag:beginner] → [tag:debutant]. Not sure the tag is really worth keeping — this is essentially a meta-tag, though it does have a use here as “resources to start learning the language”. As for [tag:etudes], I don't know what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: See [Style to be used in tag wikis' summaries?](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/160/style-to-be-used-in-tag-wikis-summaries) regarding the format of excerpts.